# How maintain user log out time in jasig cas

Tags: jsp, cas, jasig

I am jasig CAS for sso pupose for my application.i can audit the server ip,login in time for different users by using cas audit log concept.along with these i want to maintain logout time of user.is is possible? if any solution is there..pls help me..and if any links pls tell me...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you are modifying the cas source code or depending on only log 
??

Comment: actually i am doing the cas auditing as shown in https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Auditing+and+Statistics+Via+Inspektr now i want to maintain the user log out time.i am ready to change the source code also.but up to now i didnt changed it.please tell me the way to do that..

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to retriev or notsatisfied with the CAS Audit details .Please 
dig into the source code of CAS .

In the class `LogoutController` you can do your stuff.

below is the method;

```
 public LogoutController() {
        setCacheSeconds(0);
       //TO DO                   //here do your stuff

    }
```

`Note:`After modifications do not forget to make class file and replace in the war .